# One-to-many Flask | SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, one-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a one-to-many relationship using Flask and SQLAlchemy.

I want the one-to-many relationship to be as so:

"For any single movie, there can be multiple characters"

Here it what I have so far, but it is saving in my DB as one-to-one right now. (One movie to one character, saving multiple times in DB for multiple characters)

```
class Movie(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "movies"
    id = db.Column('movies_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    movie_type = db.Column('movie_type', db.Text())

    def __init__(self, movie_type):
        self.movie_type = movie_type

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Movie %r>' % self.id

class Character(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "characters"
    id = db.Column('character_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    character_description = db.Column('character_description', db.Text())

    movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('movies.movie_id'))
    movie = db.relationship('Movie', backref='characters', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, character_description, movie):
        self.character_description = character_description

        self.movie = movie

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Character %r>' % self.id
```

I am saving into the DB like this:

```
movie = models.movie(movie_type)
character = models.Character(character_description, movie)

db.session.add(movie)
db.session.add(character)
db.session.commit()
```

The end goal is to be able to look up what movie a character is in. If you could also help me out with that query, that would be great!

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I think you miss the characters relations in the movie + the insert was not totaly right.

There is also little details that you have to be carefull. Why id of movie is movieS_id and id of character is character_id ?

Also, the name of the column is the same as the name of the variable if not specified.

For example you can do that:

```
character_description = db.Column(db.Text())
```

### Anyway, without changing this details, you can try this:

```
class Movie(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "movies"
    id = db.Column('movies_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    movie_type = db.Column('movie_type', db.Text())
    characters = db.relationship("Character", backref="movie", lazy='dynamic')
    def __init__(self, movie_type):
        self.movie_type = movie_type

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Movie %r>' % self.id

class Character(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "characters"
    id = db.Column('character_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    character_description = db.Column('character_description', db.Text())

    movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('movies.movies_id'))
    movie = db.relationship('Movie')

    def __init__(self, character_description, movie):
        self.character_description = character_description

        self.movie = movie

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Character %r>' % self.id
```

### Inserting

```
c = Character(character_description='c')
c2 = Character(character_description='c2')
m = Movie(movie_type ='action')

# link characters to movie
m.characters.append(c)
m.characters.append(c2)
# or
m.characters.extend([c,c2])

db.session.add(m)
# add characters
db.session.add(c)
db.session.add(c2)
# or
db.session.add_all([c,c2])
# commit
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: thanks for your help but that did not work for me. I am still getting a one-to-one (one movie id correlates to one character) rather than one movie id correlates to many characters. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: do I need to add "movie" to __init__? If so, how do I do that while inserting. (e.g. m = Movie(movie_type ='action'), c = Character(character_description='c'), m.characters.append(c), etc...)?

Comment: Oh, I think I inverted the insertion, sorry. Try to do db.session.add(m) then db.session.add(c) then commit :)

Comment: That still results in a one-to-one :( first off, do I need "self.movie = movie" in init? If so, do I add it during insertion as so: m = Movie(movie_type ='action'), c = Character(character_description='c', __movie__), m.characters.append(c) (Note: I have also tried what I just mentioned and it does not work)

Comment: But, did you tried to add many characters to one movie ? What is inserted in db. If you add a new movie (id 5 for example), you will have 2 characters with movie_id=5.
I don't understand the "self.movie=movie". You could work on a instance of Movie already inserted in database. You just don't have to add it again.

Comment: sorry, @SunnyMalotrha I was making a mistake, change the backref of the characters relations in the Movie modiel and set it to movie. The code is already updated in my response.

Comment: thanks for all your help. How do I add multiple characters to a movie? Could you give me an example of adding 2 characters to 1 movie?

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out! Thanks again :)

Comment: I just add multiple characters adding example :)

Comment: THIS PART IS INCORRECT: 
    movie = db.relationship('Movie')  You don't need this.

Comment: @Dragu will flask-sqlalchemy automatically fill the movie_id foreign key?