# Flask SQL Alchemy Multiple join paths and one to many relationships

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a task management application in Flask and have run into the following issue.

I have 3 models, `User`, `Task` and `Project`. I would like for users to be able to create tasks and assign them to other users. This requires having multiple joins between the `Task` and `User` model.

Previously, before trying to implement this feature I had a one to many relationship from `User` to `Task` which was working fine and the two original models are below.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=True )
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref='author', lazy='dynamic') # one user has many tasks
    projects = db.relationship('Project', backref='author', lazy='dynamic') # one user has many projects

class Task(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(128))
    due = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True)
    done = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')) # task belongs to user
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id')) # task belongs to project
```

Following the [SQL Alchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths), I have added an `assigned_to_id` column to Task and an `assigned_tasks` column to User.

My models are now the following:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=True )
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    tasks_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tasks.id'))
    assigned_tasks_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tasks.id'))

    tasks = db.relationship('Task', foreign_keys="User.tasks_id", backref='author') # one user has many tasks
    assigned_tasks = db.relationship('Task', foreign_keys="User.tasks_id", backref='assigned_to') # one user has many tasks
    projects = db.relationship('Project', backref='author', lazy='dynamic') # one user has many projects

class Task(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(128))
    due = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True)
    done = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')) # task belongs to user
    assigned_to_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id')) # task belongs to project
```

As I have no constraints on tasks needing to be assigned or users needing to have assigned tasks, I assumed that I should be able to continue to create users and tasks as before. But now, when I try to create a task with an author, I get an error.

```
>>> u = User(email='test@example.com', password='password')
>>> t = Task(body='New Task', author=u)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 417, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 249, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 414, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/app/models.py", line 67, in __init__
    super(Task, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 700, in _declarative_constructor
    setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
  File "/Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 229, in __set__
    instance_dict(instance), value, None)
  File "/Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1040, in set
    given, wanted))
TypeError: Incompatible collection type: User is not list-like
```

I may have misunderstood the error here, but it seems to me that now each task expects more than one author. How do I keep the one to many relationship so that each task only expects one author still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't add a comment due to my reputation but 
[One-to-many Flask | SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375179/one-to-many-flask-sqlalchemy)

the accepted answer here should help you.
Also...

```
>>> u = User(email='test@example.com', password='password')
>>> t = Task(body='New Task', author=u)
```

**the author variable doesn't exist in the Task class as its in the User class**

You need to append the user to the task. 
You might want to review your code the relationships between the classes doesn't seem right. That or I'm mistaken.