# SqlAlchemy One-to-Many, only makes one-to-one

Tags: python, numpy, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, one-to-many

I'm trying to create a table that has many one-to-many relations to 3 separate tables. The structure and code is the same for all 3 tables, with the exception that some of the tables of more columns than other. For the sake of simplicity I've included only one of the relational tables.

Each value in the column 'symbol_col' has a relationship with every column, and inputs multiple values to every column. 
When I ran the code before I got back:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\blewi\PycharmProjects\binance\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1170, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Users\blewi\PycharmProjects\binance\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\mysqldb.py", line 105, in do_executemany
    rowcount = cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\blewi\PycharmProjects\binance\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 197, in executemany
    self._get_db().encoding)
  File "C:\Users\blewi\PycharmProjects\binance\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 234, in _do_execute_many
    rows += self.execute(sql + postfix)
  File "C:\Users\blewi\PycharmProjects\binance\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\blewi\PycharmProjects\binance\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\blewi\PycharmProjects\binance\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "C:\Users\blewi\PycharmProjects\binance\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 727, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "C:\Users\blewi\PycharmProjects\binance\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1066, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "C:\Users\blewi\PycharmProjects\binance\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 683, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "C:\Users\blewi\PycharmProjects\binance\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\Users\blewi\PycharmProjects\binance\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

I then used `try/except exc.IntegrityError as e: db.session.rollback()` and that initiated the transfer to the database, but would only commit one set.

I tried using some of the advice I found in: ([One-to-many Flask | SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375179/one-to-many-flask-sqlalchemy))
but it ended up creating more issues, and seemed to make it just as convoluted as before.

I'm new to sql and flask, so I'm trying to get some more knowledge on it, but I'd also love to see the code work.
Below is the code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy as sa
from flask import Flask as fl
from sqlalchemy import exc
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

app = fl(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 
'mysql://root:the_other_stuff'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
DEBUG = True
db = sa(app)


class symbol(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    _symbol = db.Column('symbol_col', db.VARCHAR(45))

    _time = db.relationship('time', backref='Symbol', lazy=True)

    _open_close = db.relationship('open_close', backref='Symbol', lazy=True)

    def __init__(self, id, _symbol):
        self.id = id
        self._symbol = _symbol


class time(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    open_time = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(45))
    close_time = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(45))
    symbol_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('symbol.id'))

    def __int__(self, open_time, close_time):
        self.id = id
        self.open_time = open_time
        self.close_time = close_time

def _symbol():
    for i in range(len(tickers)):
        data = tickers[i]
        id = i + 1
        db.session.add(symbol(id, data))
    db.create_all()
    return db.session.commit(), print('inserted in symbol')


_symbol()


def t_loop(a=0):
    for i in range(len(klines[a])):
        with db.session.no_autoflush:
            try:
                _symbol = symbol.query.filter(symbol._symbol == 
tickers[a]).first()
                o_t = klines[a][i][0]
                c_t = klines[a][i][6]
                id = i + 1
                db.session.add(time(id=id, open_time=o_t, close_time=c_t, 
Symbol=_symbol))
                db.session.commit()
            except exc.IntegrityError as e:
                db.session.rollback()
    if a < len(klines) - 1:
        a = a + 1
        t_loop(a=a)
    return print('inserted time')


t_loop(a=0)

db.create_all()
db.session.commit()
```

I changed the above code to be more like the link I attached. It's now inputting multiple of each symbol, and looks like it might have succeeded?

```
    class symbol(db.Model):

        id = db.Column('symbol_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        symbol_col = db.Column('symbol_col', db.VARCHAR(45))

        _time = db.relationship('time', backref='Symbol', lazy=True)


    def __init__(self, symbol_col):
        self.symbol_col = symbol_col

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<symbol %r>' % self.id


    class time(db.Model):
        id = db.Column('time_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        open_time = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(45))
        close_time = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(45))
        symbol_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('symbol.symbol_id'))
        symbols = db.relationship('symbol')

        def __int__(self, open_time, close_time, symbols):
            self.open_time = open_time
            self.close_time = close_time
            self.symbols = symbols

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<time %r>' % self.id

def t_loop(a=0):
    for i in range(len(klines[a])):
        try:
            s = symbol(symbol_col=tickers[a])
            t = time(open_time=klines[a][i][0], close_time=klines[a][i][6])
            s._time.append(t)
            db.session.add(s)
            db.session.add(t)

        except exc.IntegrityError as e:
            db.session.rollback()
        if a < len(klines) - 1:
            a = a + 1
            t_loop(a=a)
        return print('inserted time')


    t_loop(a=0)
```

Comment: The error seems to have nothing to do with relationship configuration and looks like you're simply trying to insert a row with a duplicate primary key value. Without you providing the full traceback instead of just the error message it is hard to say anything for sure, but `t_loop()` looks like a good candidate for duplicates, because it is recursive and uses the range variable `i` as primary key. Of course `_symbol()` has the same issue, if you run this program more than once.

Comment: I edited the original post to include the full traceback. `i + 1` is the full primary key, but `i` is the symbol, which should then create a new primary key for that symbol, no? Shouldn't the fact that it's a different symbol that it's tethered to negate the fact that it's the same number?

Comment: The traceback still does not contain from where in your code it originated. I don't understand what you mean by "different symbol". In `for i in range(len(tickers)):` the variable `i` is bound to integers beginning from 0. You then use those integers as the primary key. If you run this script more than once, you will get the integrity error due to duplicate primary key value. You could for example simply omit passing an `id` value altogether and let the autoincrementing default handle it, but you'd have to refactor the `__init__` methods a bit.

Comment: I made some edits, and I think I understand what you mean now by the integers being wrong. Does the code I added at the bottom of the post look better? I went back and looked at the link I included, and it made more sense after your advice.

Comment: What is the role of `symbol_col` in`symbol`? Is it a stock symbol? In that case it'd seem like it should be a (non-primary)  key, or in other words have a unique constraint. That on the other hand complicates things a bit in `t_loop`, since you cannot then simply add a new symbol each time you add a `time` entity, but you'd have to for example try and fetch the `symbol` for the stock symbol at hand and if not found, then create it.