# How to store multiple image filepaths in flask sqlachemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a webpage with a Project class and Project class will have multiple image files.
I can upload and store the image files but can't insert the file paths of images to database. So i can call the image paths from db. I have a sqlite db and i use Flask-SQLAlchemy.
Here is my Project Class. I've messed up a bit.

```
class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    header_image = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default='default_project.jpg')
    project_images = db.relationship('ImageSet', backref='project', lazy=True, uselist=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Project('{self.title}', {self.date_posted}')"


class ImageSet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    imageset = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'), nullable=False)
```

And this is the route and function to add projects

```
def save_picture(form_picture):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_picture.filename)
    picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/images/project_images', picture_fn)
    output_size = (1280, 720)
    i = Image.open(form_picture)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.save(picture_path)

    return picture_fn


@app.route('/add_project', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def add_project():
        form = AddProjectForm()
        imageset = ImageSet()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            if form.header_image.data:
                header_image = save_picture(form.header_image.data)
            if form.project_images.data:
                for image in form.project_images.data:
                    image = save_picture(image)
            project = Project(title=form.title.data, description=form.description.data, project_images=, user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(project)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Project Successfully Added', 'succes')
            return render_template('add_project.html', title='Add Project', form=form)
        return render_template('add_project.html', title='Add Project', form=form)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375179/one-to-many-flask-sqlalchemy

Comment: @JosefKorbel thank you. now i know where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JosefKorbel, i've figured out the solution.
For anyone who may need the answer of the problem:

I used one-to-many relationship in classes.

```
class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    header_image = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default='default_project.jpg')
    project_images = db.relationship('ImageSet', backref='project_images', lazy=True, uselist=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Project('{self.title}', {self.date_posted}')"


class ImageSet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    image = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'), nullable=False)
```

Route, image saving functions:

```
def save_picture(form_picture):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_picture.filename)
    picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/images/project_images', picture_fn)
    output_size = (1280, 720)
    i = Image.open(form_picture)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.save(picture_path)

    return picture_fn


@app.route('/add_project', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def add_project():
    form = AddProjectForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.header_image.data:
            header_image = save_picture(form.header_image.data)
        project = Project(title=form.title.data, description=form.description.data, header_image=header_image, user_id=current_user.id)
        if form.project_images.data:
            for image in form.project_images.data:
                image = save_picture(image)
                project.project_images.append(ImageSet(image=image))
                time.sleep(2)
        db.session.add(project)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Project Successfully Added', 'succes')
        return render_template('add_project.html', title='Add Project', form=form)
    return render_template('add_project.html', title='Add Project', form=form)
```

i used `time.sleep(2)` before proccessing each image because sqlite is locking the database if i dont wait.